# How to measure http requests per second using micrometer

Tags: java, rest, instrumentation, statsd, micrometer

We have a rest service developed using vert.x with large number of requests coming every seconds. I am using StatsdMeterRegistry for other metrics like Timer to measure taken to process different business logics. How do i gauge http requests coming every second  using micrometer. on my local I have installed statsd agent and carbon/graphite/whisper but in production it will be statsd and sysdig. Not using spring framework or spring boot. I can't use vertx in built support for micrometer as it doesn't support statsd. Does micrometer provide inbuilt Meters for http requests rate. Or any different way you can suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Micrometer is a simple facade for metrics. You should be able to leverage the built in micrometer support and just plug in the correct backend.

Here is how you would create the statsd registry and register it with vertx:

```
StatsdConfig config = new StatsdConfig() {
    @Override
    public String get(String k) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public StatsdFlavor flavor() {
        return StatsdFlavor.Etsy;
    }
};

MeterRegistry registry = new StatsdMeterRegistry(config, Clock.SYSTEM);

Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx(new VertxOptions()
  .setMetricsOptions(new MicrometerMetricsOptions()
    .setMicrometerRegistry(registry)
    .setEnabled(true)));
```

Docs:
http://micrometer.io/docs/registry/statsD#_configuring and https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-micrometer-metrics/java/#_other_backends_or_combinations

Comment: Thanks a lot. This will help.

Comment: there is no such method as setMicrometerRegistry

Comment: The docs mention the method. My only guess is you need to upgrade Vertx versions